# Ef6, Many to many, Inserts and Primary keys

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I have a problem with populating the right values in a junction table for a many to many relationship. In the image below I have simplified what I am trying to do. The "Table on the left" has values in the database that I want to use. The table of the right is about to receive new records. It has a navigation property to the Junction table and the same is true for the table on the left. The junction table has navigation properties to both tables on its rear and **they are set to required**.

[image]

When I create the new records in the table on the right, I also add to it records in the junction table. The TOL_ID is known as it is saved in the database, but the TOR_ID is about to be created, therefore unknown. When I attempt to call the **SaveChanges** in my context, it tries to save the junction table records first, before the TOR_IDs have been populated for the record on the right. I though that marking the navigation property as **Required** would make the EF understand that TOR_ID must exist before creating the junction table row. Instead it tries to insert an existing TOL_ID and 0, which gives a violation when trying to insert many table on the right records connected to the same TOL_ID.

**Note:** Saving the TOR_IDs first and then connecting with junction records is not an option, as the creation of the junction table records are part of a "[Slowly changing dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension)" type 6 flow.

This is how it really looks like in the code:

```
// The newRating is the new object corresponding the Table on the right
var newRating = new ModuleRating() 
{ 
    // The moduleRating.RatedDriveUnit already exists in the db
    RatedDriveUnit = moduleRating.RatedDriveUnit 
};

newModule.Ratings.Add(newRating);
```

Comment: Can you provide the code that is processing the records?

Comment: @S.Dav I will post it above.

Comment: You must add JT_ID to TOR and TOL tables.

Comment: @Mehmet There is a JT_ID actually. The problem is that the TOR_ID of the junction table becomes 0 when it is about to be inserted. If TOR had been inserted first, the TOR_ID would have had an identity which in turn would be used for the generation of the junction table property.

Comment: @Mehmet, sorry did you mean that I should have a JT_ID in both tables? Why? A many to many should contain foreign keys. The tables containing those foreign keys should not need to have a reference to an ID of a junction table. In that case I would be able to join only 1 TOR to 1 TOL, which is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the Code First below classes will helpful

```
public class TOL
{
    [Key]
    public int TOL_ID { get; set; }
    public int Col1 { get; set; }

    public ICollection<TOR> Tors { get; set; }
}

public class TOR
{
    [Key]
    public int TOR_ID { get; set; }
    public int Col1 { get; set; }

    public ICollection<TOL> Tols { get; set; }
}

public class TolTorContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<TOL> Tols { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TOR> Tors { get; set; }
}
```

If you follow database first approach,make FK at Join Table and try to chhange id names TOLId , TORId

Answer (score 0):

I'am sorry for spending your time. After some investigation I noticed that the supposed composite unique index (TOL_ID and TOR_ID) of the junction table had been set wrong. Instead two separate unique indexes had been applied to TOL_ID and TOR_ID, which resulted a constrain violation as soon as one of those two values appeared twice.